# Load image using KNN in SimpleCV

Tags: python, knn, simplecv

This code used to train some image using KNN in simpleCV but only class 8 and 9 which extracted. The other class just show warning:

> WARNING: No features extracted - bailing

This is the code :

```
from SimpleCV import *

image_dirs = ['N Titrasi\1%',
              'N Titrasi\2%',
              'N Titrasi\3%',
              'N Titrasi\4%',
              'N Titrasi\5%',
              'N Titrasi\6%',
              'N Titrasi\7%',
              'N Titrasi\8%',
              'N Titrasi\9%',
              'N Titrasi\10%',
              'N Titrasi\11%',
              'N Titrasi\12%',
              'N Titrasi\13%',
              'N Titrasi\14%',
              'N Titrasi\15%',
              'N Titrasi\16%',
              'N Titrasi\17%',
              'N Titrasi\18%',
              'N Titrasi\19%',
              'N Titrasi\20%'
              ]
test_dirs =  ['N Urea\1%',
              'N Urea\2%',
              'N Urea\3%',
              'N Urea\4%',
              'N Urea\5%',
              'N Urea\6%',
              'N Urea\7%',
              'N Urea\8%',
              'N Urea\9%',
              'N Urea\10%',
              'N Urea\11%',
              'N Urea\12%',
              'N Urea\13%',
              'N Urea\14%',
              'N Urea\15%',
              'N Urea\16%',
              'N Urea\17%',
              'N Urea\18%',
              'N Urea\19%',
              'N Urea\20%'              
              ]

class_names = ['1%',
               '2%',
               '3%',
               '4%',
               '5%',
               '6%',
               '7%',
               '8%',
               '9%',
               '10%',
               '11%',
               '12%',
               '13%',
               '14%',
               '15%',
               '16%',
               '17%',
               '18%',
               '19%',
               '20%'
               ]

feature_extractors = []
extractor_names = []

extractor_name = 'hue'
feature_extractor = HueHistogramFeatureExtractor()
feature_extractors.append(feature_extractor)
extractor_names.append(extractor_name)

classifier = KNNClassifier(feature_extractors, k=3)

classifier.train(image_dirs, class_names,subset=-1,disp=None, savedata='train.txt', verbose=True)
classifier.test(test_dirs, class_names,subset=-1,disp=None, savedata='test.txt', verbose=True)
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: Are the slash characters in your paths escaped correctly?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The slash characters is wrong. Thanks